# App to play the 360° panorama videos

Tags: macos, video-player

I've got 360° panorama videos taken by [Gear 360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Gear_360) camera which I'd like to view on macOS.

I've tried to watch them in VLC, but without success. They're displayed as flat spherical videos when opened.

Which app can I use to play these 360° panorama videos?

---

I expect it should have the feature to look-around by using cursors or a mouse, similarly when that kind of videos are displayed on YouTube or Facebook.

Ideally, it should be free to use, but I am open for suggestions.